# Fetch the value for the latest date in the index row

Tags: python

my table looks something like this:

| Sector | 4/1/2022 | 5/1/2022 | 6/1/2022 | 1Y Min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 05 | 12 | 05 |
| B | 18 | 20 | 09 | 09 |
| C | 02 | 09 | 12 | 02 |

I want to add a new column "Bps away from 1Y Min" such that values of the new column is calculated using the formula: (Value as of the latest date - 1Y Min)
I want to keep the latest date column dynamic within the formula such that it gets updated whenever a column with a new date is available.

For eg:-

| Sector | 4/1/2022 | 5/1/2022 | 6/1/2022 | 1Y Min | Bps away from 1Y Min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 05 | 12 | 05 | 7 |
| B | 18 | 20 | 09 | 09 | 0 |
| C | 02 | 09 | 12 | 02 | 10 |

Comment: Add what you tried and the problem that you faced while trying. Don't just put the question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a helper function to find the max date from the column names (and assigning suitably low values for non-dates), and then it's just pandas.

```
import datetime
def dt_helper(dt_string):
    try:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(dt_string, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
    except:
        return datetime.date(1900,1,1)

df['Bps away from 1Y Min'] = df[max(df.columns, key=dt_helper)] - df['1Y Min']
```

It's not clear if your dates are dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy, I've assumed the former, but if the latter then change the date pattern to `'%m/%d/%Y'`

Comment: I am very new to python. Can you walk me through how the helper function in working in this code?

Comment: Sure - the helper function will attempt to convert a string to a date.  It expects the string in the format 'dd/mm/yyyy'.  If a string is in that format then it converted to a datetime object.  If the string can't be convert then the `except` block will return it as a very old datetime object.  So, all columns will be converted to a datetime objects which can then be sorted, and so the concept of a `max` value is properly defined when applying the helper function as a key.

Comment: I ran the code again and this time, df[max(df.columns, key=dt_helper)] part of the code is picking up value as of the oldest date. I am struggling to understand what is causing the issue.

Comment: @Saanchi Happy for you to send me the details - my contact details are in my profile.